# Macro that accepts an expression referencing variables defined by the macro

Tags: rust, macros, hygiene

Is it possible to write a macro:

```rust
my_macro!(left + right)
```

that gets transformed into:

```rust
{
    let left = 0;
    let right = 1;
    $expr
}
```

where the variables are defined inside the macro? The user of the macro knows that `left` and `right` are special variable names.

Comment: IIRC macro hygiene disallows this, but you could do something like `my_macro!(|left, right| left + right)`. It would not necessarily have to even be a closure; the defined macro syntax could take `| $l:ident , $r:ident |` and then use `$l` and `$r` as the identifier names. The important thing is that the caller of the macro needs to specify them.

Comment: I think this should be possible with a procedural macro

Answer (score 2):

A declarative macro can't because of hygiene, but a very basic procedual macro can:

```rust
use proc_macro2::TokenStream;
#[proc_macro]
pub fn foo(i: proc_macro::TokenStream) -> proc_macro::TokenStream {
    let i: TokenStream = i.into();
    quote::quote! {
        {
            let x = 1;
            #i
        }
    }
    .into()
}
```

when called with:

```rust
println!("{}", foo!(x + 1));
```

will print "2".